# Trouble writing c++ split_rope function

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am trying to write a split rope function for a rope data structure so I can make an insert at index I function. I found a Java implementation of retrieving a substring from indexes start to end and I am trying to use those concepts from it to create a C++ function for splitting the rope

I have referenced the Wikipedia article and Original paper (linked below), but they are pretty vague. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.9450&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Here is the link to the code I am referencing:
https://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-rope/

```
string substring(int start, int end){
            string str = "";
            bool found = false;
            Node *temp = root;
            if (end > temp->weight) {
                found = true;
                end -= temp->weight;
                if (start > temp->weight) {
                    start -= temp->weight;
                    str = temp->right->data[substring(start, end)];
                    return str;
                } else
                    str = temp->right->data[substring(0, end)];            
            }        
            if (!found){
                while (end <= temp->weight)
                    temp = temp->left;
                end -= temp->weight;
                if (start >= temp->weight){
                    start -= temp->weight;
                    str = temp->right->data[substring(start, end)] + str;
                    return str;
                }
                str = temp->right->data[substring(0, end)];            
            }    
            temp = temp->left;
            while (start < temp->weight){
                str = temp->right->data + str;
                temp = temp->left;
            }
            start -= temp->weight;
            str = temp->right->data[substring(start, end) + str];    

            return str;        
        }
```

The function above is supposed to return a substring of the rope from int start to int end. I am receiving a `no operator "[]" matches these operands -- operand types are: char * [ std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> ]` error from it.

I would want to try another type implementation if possible, but I couldn't find any more in-depth documentation on this function

As requested, here is the other code I have written. If you have a suggestion on how to better implement split into my code, that would be greatly appreciated

```
class Rope {   // Rope data structure
private:

    class Node {
    public:
        char *data;
        int weight;
        Node *left, *right;
        Node(char *data) : data(data), weight(sizeof(data)/sizeof(char)), left(nullptr), right(nullptr){}
        Node() : data(nullptr), weight(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr){}
    };

    Node* root;

public:
    Rope() : root(new Node()) {}

    // Rope(const char str[]) {}
    // Rope(const char str[], int len) {}

    void makeEmpty () {
        root = new Node();
    }

    void concat(char *str) {    // concats string and rope
        Node *temp = new Node(str);
        Node *newRoot = new Node();
        newRoot->left = root;
        newRoot->right = temp;
        newRoot->weight = newRoot->left->weight;
        if (newRoot->left->right != nullptr) {
            newRoot->weight += newRoot->left->right->weight;
        }
        root = newRoot;   
    }

    void concatRope(const Rope& r1, const Rope& r2){ // concats 2 ropes
        Node *newRoot = new Node();
        newRoot->left = r1.root;
        newRoot->right = r2.root;
        newRoot->weight = newRoot->left->weight;
        if (newRoot->left->right != nullptr){
            newRoot->weight += newRoot->left->right->weight;
        }
        root = newRoot;
    }
```

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the definition of the `Node` class (and any other classes it references).

Comment: I think this line `str = temp->right->data[substring(start, end)];` looks like it is wrong. Depending on what `data` is, you either want to call `data.substring()` or directly call `temp->right->substring`.
You are basically providing a `string` to the `operator[]`, which should be probably an `index` rather than a `string`.

Comment: I tried to apply what the person did in java to c++ and then modify that substring class to be a split class. I don't think it is going to work. Do you know of a good resource that has a "spected out" split_rope class?